# getting error while trying to rotate array clock wise using stack

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, rotation

Given an unsorted array arr[] of size N, rotate it by D elements (clockwise).

Input
The first line of the input contains T denoting the number of testcases. First line of each test case contains two space separated elements, N denoting the size of the array and an integer D denoting the number size of the rotation. Subsequent line will be the N space separated array elements

Output
For each testcase, in a new line, output the rotated array

Example
Input
1 2 3 4 5

Output
3 4 5 1 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
void rotate(int *a,int s,int r) {
    stack<int> st;
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++) {
        st.push(a[i]);
    }
    for(int j=r;j<s;j++) {
        a[j-r] = a[j];
    }
    for(int k=s-1;k>r+1;k--) {
        a[k] = st.top();
        st.pop();
    }
    for(int l=0;l<s;l++) {
        cout<<a[l]<<" ";
    }
}
int main() {
    //code
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--) {
        int N,r;
        cin>>N>>r;
        int A[N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            cin>>A[i];
        }
        rotate(A,N,r);
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include the actual errors you get. If it's build-errors then copy-paste them as text, in full and complete, into the question.

Comment: A possible hint about *one* error in the code you show: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. You might be interested to learn about [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your logic, it seems like there is problem in your backfill part.

```
    for(int k=s-1;k>=s-r;k--) { // change k>r+1 to k>=s-r
        a[k] = st.top();
        st.pop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry my bad, int third for loop in rotate function there should be k>s-r-1